# Escaping xml tag in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, escaping

I have an input xml, say:

```
<myxml>
    <myelement id="1" />
    <myelement id="2" />
    <myelement id="3" />
</myxml>
```

I want to create an XSLT that creates an output xml of a different form, say:

```
<theirxml>
    <theirelement id="1" />
    <theirelement id="2" />
    <theirelement id="3" />
</theirxml>
```

Since I cannot create an xslt with a tag inside a tag (e.g. something like "<theirelement id="<xslt:...>" >" I found a way to do it with CDATA as follows (presented is only the relevant part of the xslt):

```
<xsl:for-each select="myxml/myelement">
    <xsl:text><![CDATA[<theirelement id="]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name" /><xsl:text><![CDATA[" />]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However the produced output does not contain "<theirelement ..." but rather "&lt;theirelement ...". I need the output to actually contain "<" and not "&lt;" (same goes for ">" and "&gt;").

The reason, btw, is because the output from this process is an input for some program that fails to read the xml when the tags are escaped as "&lt;tag&gt;".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stylesheet that does the desired transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <myxml>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </myxml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myelement">
        <theirelement>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
        </theirelement>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @fred02138 can be simplified to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <myxml>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </myxml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myelement">
        <theirelement id="{@id}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The construct in curly braces is an "attribute value template", in case you want to look it up in an XSLT reference.